# Linux Mint Install Fails (Because of Partitioning?)

Tags: linux, partitioning, linux-mint

I bought a laptop with three drives: sda/sdb are a RAID array with windows installed, and sdc is a separate 1TB drive.  While I wanted to install Linux Mint on sda/sdb (creating a new partition from its free space), that doesn't seem possible with the Mint installer, so instead I'm trying to install to sdc.

The problem is I can't get it to work.  At first I tried the following partitions:

1. 100gb ext4
2. 100gb swap
3. 800gb ntfs (to share files between Linux and Windows)

That didn't work: the install failed near the end.  So then I swapped the order of the partitions:

1. 100gb swap
2. 100gb ext4
3. 800gb ntfs

Now the install succeeds, but when Mint boots up I wind up with a black screen <strike>(even if I choose the failsafe boot)</strike>.

I'm guessing the problem is my partitioning, since I've never had issues before on other computers when I let Linux Mint do the partitioning for me.  So, my question is, what am I doing wrong?  Do I need a boot partition?  Some other type of partition?  Different partition order or size?

I haven't done partitioning "by hand" in years and I really don't know what "the right" partitions should be, so any help would be appreciated.

***EDIT***

Using Xen2050's answer I was able to see the console output.  The last part of it was:

```
...
* Starting enable remaining boot-time encrypted block devices
[   84.874610] INFO: rcu_sched detected stalls on CPU/tasks:
```

Then after a pause, there are repeated lines like this one:

```
task kworker/0:0:4 blocked for more than 120 seconds
```

Also I figured out that recovery mode actually did work, I just wasn't realizing it because of an unrelated monitor issue.  So now I know that recovery mode works, but regular mode makes my kworker tasks get blocked and my cru_sched stall (whatever that means).

Is there any way to figure out what recovery mode is doing to fix things, and then apply that to the normal boot?

Comment: Does Mint give some regular startup messages or splash screen (ESC should exit the splash screen  & show messages, or remove the boot options `quiet` and `splash). As in, is it finding the right partitions and starting to boot, then failing? Or is it not finding or trying to boot Mint at all?

Answer (score 0):

Does Mint give some regular startup messages or splash screen when trying now? (ESC should exit the splash screen  & show messages, or remove the boot options `quiet` and `splash).

As in, is it finding the right partitions and starting to boot, then failing? Or is it not finding or trying to boot Mint at all?

"Failsafe" should add all the regulars like `nomodeset` which is a big one for "black screen"...

And any other monitors or video cards/ports? I've seen some Linuxes (Linuxii?) would pick a different port/plug than the one the monitor was in.

Booting the command line option `text` should get to a terminal, to at least see if the partitions and hopefully "basic" video/monitor settings are working. Then you'd know it's some other graphics/video setting that's being changed later, and can fix that.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I was able to see the console output, and I edited my answer to include it.  If you have any idea how to interpret that output it would be very helpful, as I'm not sure what to make of it.